Extending the road maintenance example
I have a situtation where my problem domain matches closely with the road maintenance example so I'm trying to use that as my reference.
The area I need to extend the example is the relationship beteen Job -> Crew.  Image for a second where mutliple Crew's could be assigned to the same job (maybe to finish faster, maybe to place more priority on job 1 vs job 2).  In order to do so I thought I would do the following:

Change the Job.crew from a singleton to a List
Change the @PlanningVariable to a @PlanningListVariable annotation
Update appropriate gettings/setters/constructors... (ensure List is not null upon creation)

However, I now get the effort basic planning variables and list planning variables are not supported in the same entity class.
How would one go about extending the example to support a List of Crews?


Change the @PlanningVariable to a @PlanningListVariable annotation

In your case, you don't want to do that: the order of the Crews assigned to that Job doesn't matter. But the @PlanningListVariable would optimize on it (and currently doesn't support being combined with the normal var, so it's a dead end today).
Proposal A)
Instead, follow the "seat pattern" (not yet documented). Basically, give each Job a fixed List<JobSeat>. Each JobSeat has a Job and a @PlanningVariable Crew (which is no longer on Job).
The trouble with this approach is that the auto-configuration doesn't just work: you need custom moves and a whole bunch of other pain.
Proposal B) // Recommended
Use the Examination example hack. The trouble is we didn't port that one to timefold-quickstarts. You can find the code here.
Look at Exam, LeadingExam and FollowingExam. Rename Job to JobSeat and make it abstract. Extend JobSet ast PrimaryJobSeat and SecondaryJobSeat.
The abstract JobSeat has 1 planning variable (crew).
The PrimaryJobSeat has 1 extra planning variable (start). The SecondaryJobSeat has a fixed PrimaryJobSeat and uses the same start time.

Important note: the maintenance scheduling quickstart uses the Time Grain pattern. That doesn't scale well if the time grains are small (below 1 hour) or the time period is long (weeks). You might be much better off with Vehicle Routing implementation that uses the Chained through time pattern (see docs), such as our Field Service Routing model's REST API that is often used to schedule maintenance technicians. It depends on your use case.

Thanks for the response.  I've looked thru the example and have some basic questions, any help would be appreciated.

What is the purpose of the leading/following exam objects (and hence the Primary/Secondary Job).  I don't see FollowingExam used anywhere in the exam project.
I don't see how these new project objects enable 1..n crew assignments.


Hi Geoffrey, did you happen to see my follow on questions above?
